# How to design a relational schema to show a list of posts and show if I have liked it or not (like Facebook)?

Tags: list, schema, feed, relational

I would like to show a list of items/ posts. However, this list should be accompanied by a like/vote/some other action button. If the user has already done this action it should be marked in the list.

I am not sure that every time, retrieving the list of items(item ids) I have liked/voted should be retrieved and the (list of)posts be checked against it.

Alternatively a non-relational schema may be available. However, I want to efficiently implement this in a relational setup.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which technology you 'll use to create your application but for me today the best way is to begin with the object model and relational model could be generate and the same for non-relational schema.

Comment: I am using Python with MySQL. are you suggesting, storing the list of users who like/vote the post as a property of the post? If yes, how can this be done in a compact manner?

Comment: Do you use djengo ? To response I'll say yes, in a list, after in relational model it'll create a link table to resolve the many-to-many relation. In no sql it could be other kind of structure (ex : json list of user ids)